# How to progressively render react components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working with lists that will likely be in the range of 500 up to maybe 5000 items. Each item in the list will show as a component, like so:

List

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="ItemList">
      <Info items={this.props.items} />
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map( item =>
          <Item item={item} key={item._id} refresh={this.props.refresh} />
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Item

```
render() {
  var item = this.props.item;

  return (
    <li onClick={() => this.setState({showInfo: !this.state.showInfo})} 
                 className="Item">
      <h3 className={this.state.showInfo ? "item-title-bar active" : "item-title-bar"}>
        <div>
          <div className="item-category">
            {item.category} 
          </div>
          <div className="item-name">
            {item.name}
          </div>
        </div>
      </h3>

      {this.state.showInfo &&
        <ItemInfo item={this.props.item} refresh={this.props.refresh} />
      }
    </li>
  );
}
```

Once one of these lists gets up to around 1000 items, it's noticeably slow when I click to show a different list. Perf tools are showing me 90-150 ms for displaying this list at 1000 or 2000 items. Not sure I can get around that as long as I'm rendering them.

So, what I'm trying to do:

1. Can I let the initial items update, then render others in the background, while the app remains responsive?
2. How can I show initial items, then load more as the user scrolls down the page?

If neither option works, I'll probably try to load a few, then add a show more or show all button at the bottom of the list. Want to make this as seamless as possible though, open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: You can try modules like [`react-list`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-list), [`react-list-lazy-load`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-list-lazy-load) or [`react-lazy-load`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load). They probably all solve your problem with the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) would be my first choice when dealing with a virtual list. Lot of examples here: https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List

Pretty simple if you know the heights of the items ahead of time, but can use the [CellMeasurer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md) component if you don't.

Comment: Of libraries suggested, this one seems to most mature and diverse. And it's probably the best answer to the questions as I've phrased it. react-lazy-load gets points for being simplest to use though.

Running into issues due to wanting list elements that can change heights when user clicks. I think react-virtualized might do the trick with masonry + windowscroller + maybe cell measure. But I'll need to mess with it more. Don't want the question to linger though, so I'll go ahead and accept. Thanks for pointing me in the right directions!